# Rate of convergence and asymptotic dominance in $\Vert x \Vert \gg \Vert(\hat\beta-\beta)\cdot u\Vert $

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, probability

Let $\Vert A \Vert$ denote the spectral norm of a random matrix. Let $x$ and $u_k$ be N$\times$T matrices. Denote $\beta \cdot u = \sum_{k=1}^K\beta_ku_k $, where $\beta$ is a K-vector and $\beta_k$ a scalar. Further, let $\Vert x \Vert = O_p(\sqrt N)$ and $\Vert u_k \Vert = O_p(\sqrt{NT})$ for all $k=1,...,K$ as N and T grow at the same rate.

Why do we have $\Vert x \Vert \gg \Vert(\hat\beta-\beta)\cdot u\Vert $ asymptotically if the convergence rate of $\hat\beta$ to $\beta$ is faster than $\sqrt N$?

Comment: "...convergence rate of $\hat\beta$ is faster than $\sqrt N$ (that is, if $\Vert\hat\beta-\beta\Vert=o_p(\sqrt N)$..." So according to you, if $\Vert\hat\beta-\beta\Vert=O(N^{  \frac{1}{4}  }) = o_p(\sqrt N)$, i.e. $\Vert\hat\beta-\beta\Vert$ diverges to $\infty$ at the rate $N^{  \frac{1}{4}  }$, then "...convergence rate of $\hat\beta$ is faster than $\sqrt N$..."?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, @Michael. The "if" in the parenthesis should not have been there. Now should be correct, I was just trying to clarify that it is the rate of convergence of the estimator to its true value $\beta$ what I referred to.

Comment: What does $\gg$ mean? What is $\cdot$ ? In general, for any operator norm, one has the formula, $\| A\xi \| \leq \|A\| \|\xi\|$, where $\|A\|$ is the operator norm of $A$, and $\| \xi \|$ and $\| A\xi \|$ are vector norms. If you get your formulation straight, the claim probably follows immediately.

Comment: $f(s) \ll g(s)$ is equivalent to $f(s) =
O(g(s))$ and $\cdot$ is just the dot product

Comment: dot product between the (presumably) vector β^−β and the matrix u ("Let x and u be N by T matrices...")? As I said, try applying the standard operator norm estimate on the quantity ||u(β^−β)||, and your claim follows.

Comment: You are right, the notation was a mess. Now should be fine, note that it is $u_k$ that is NxT

Comment: So I have $\Vert(\hat\beta-\beta)\cdot u\Vert \leq \Vert(\hat\beta-\beta)\Vert \Vert u \Vert = O_p(Z)O_p(\sqrt{NT})$ where $Z>\sqrt N$ (using that $o_p(Z)$ implies $O_p(Z)$). Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: The definition of "..convergence rate of β^ to β is faster than root-N..." means ||β^−β|| is little-o_p(1/(root-N)). Convergence means ||β^−β|| goes to zero in some sense, not O_p(Z) where Z > something that blows up.

Comment: Right. So we have $\Vert(\hat\beta-\beta)\cdot u\Vert \leq O_p(\sqrt T)$, hence for T and N that grow at the same rate we have $\Vert(\hat\beta-\beta)\cdot u\Vert = O_p(\sqrt N)$, which is basically the idea of asymptotic dominance that we have in $\Vert x \Vert \gg \Vert(\hat\beta-\beta)\cdot u\Vert$. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, since you said "...faster than root-N rate..." rather than "...at the root-N rate...", it would be $\Vert(\hat\beta-\beta)\cdot u\Vert \leq o_p(\sqrt T)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help!